# Light sensor not working after Lollipop update

Tags: nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop, sensors

After upgrading my Nexus 5 to Android OS version 5.0 Lollipop, an issue has occurred: light sensor doesn't work properly when I am trying to call someone. Screen always stays on and I am not able to have a proper conversion, because I accidentally touch the screen with my cheek and, for example, mute my microphone...

Would factory reset help me solve this issue? Or maybe you have any other tips on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Try downloading CPU-Z from the app store and see if the proximity sensor is working right.  When you get into the app, go to the "Sensors" tab, and on Proximity, it should read 8, then if you put your hand close or over it, it should read 0.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "proximity sensor", not "light sensor" although it might be using same hardware.

Comment: Funny, but using a flip cover will prevent any accidental touching of your screen. ;) While on a call you can close the flip and talk.

Comment: It seems to be a bug on 5.0 affecting some Nexus 5 devices. Many are facing this issue.. I heard that Google support will started working on this issue with their specialist team to get this bug patched and fixed. You will receive and update via OTA once they address all the bugs from reported users.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with lollipop and it has been reported to google. Until google fix the issue you need to lock screen using power button manually.